# How to distinguish Bose glass and superfluid phases in a harmonic trap?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, cold-atoms

In mean-field study of Bose-Hubbard model in an optical lattice, what parameter can be calculated to distinguish Bose glass and superfluid in a harmonic trap?